# How to implement queueing in Quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, priority-queue, job-scheduling

I have a system that allows the user to schedule reports but those jobs can be scheduled all at the same time.

How can I implement a queuing system in quartz where those jobs scheduled at the same time will be executed one by one and not concurrently?

Comment: Seems like sequential tasks. Why don't to consider event driven approach. Completion of one task triggers one event and so on.

Comment: I can try that but i'm not sure how can implement this with the Quartz Scheduler.

Comment: Instead of scheduling a new job for each single report, schedule only one global job to execute periodically, and make that job retrieve the queued reports and produce them one by one. The report queue can be a simple DB table, or a JMS queue, or an in-memory object, or even an email account...

Comment: Thanks @walen for the suggestion. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're need is execute job in clusters mode, please read the next article 
[Cluster Jobs](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/how-to-quartz-scheduler-with-clustering-in-jee-application-with-mysql.html)

Comment: i think this was design to handle multiple Scheduler instance. I only have 1 instance in my system.